# Mongoose on save does not honor select:false after saving document

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema defined as below

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

interface UserPreferences {
    departmentId: string;
    email: string;
    default: object;
}

const SchemaModel = model<UserPreferences>('user-preferences', new Schema<UserPreferences>({
    departmentId: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
    email: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, select: false},
    default: {type: Object, required: false},
}));

export default SchemaModel;
```

When I save new object as below

```
...
const userPref = new UserPreferencesModel({
            departmentId,
            email,
            default:{a:10}
        }));
return res.status(201).send(await userPref.save());
```

Here response I get is

```
        {
            departmentId: 'department1',// Must not be their
            email : 'jagdish@gmail.com',// Must not be their as select: false
            default : {a:10}
        }
```

I have lot's of fields like that, any way to send result(without another query to DB) where select: false values will not be sent to end user?

Comment: The docs state that `select` specifies a default projection _for queries_, but you're not running a query, you're saving a document.